# Compare and check if multiple variables, both reference types and value types, in object has changed in C#

Tags: c#

In a system we are dependent on a third party service and once every minute we download data from them and update our data. It is related to E-signing so it is a lot of fields to update. Right now we are getting all the information and then we do an update on our side even if nothing has changed.

My thought was to do a deep copy using any of the methods shown below and then compare the values. However since there are so many variables I wonder if there is someway I can compare all values and see if they are equal and not have to write code to check each variable? An agreement as shown below have both value and reference types.

```
public class Agreement
{
    //Properties here, both value and reference types

    public bool HasChanged(Agreement oldagreement)
    {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

Method example:

```
var oldagreement = agreement.Clone();

var document = client.GetThirdPartyAgreement(agreement.AgreementDocumentId);

UpdateDocument(agreement, document);

if(agreement.HasChanged(oldagreement)
{
   agreementRepository.Update(agreement);
}
```

Deep copy extension methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Perform a deep Copy of the object, using Json as a serialisation method. NOTE: Private members are not cloned using this method.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being copied.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The object instance to copy.</param>
/// <returns>The copied object.</returns>
public static T CloneJson<T>(this T source)
{
    // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    // initialize inner objects individually
    // for example in default constructor some list property initialized with some values,
    // but in 'source' these items are cleaned -
    // without ObjectCreationHandling.Replace default constructor values will be added to result
    var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source), deserializeSettings);
}

/// <summary>
/// Perform a deep Copy of the object.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being copied.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The object instance to copy.</param>
/// <returns>The copied object.</returns>
public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
    }

    // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (stream)
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to know exactly what did change or just "something changed"? If the latter, have you considered using just serializing both old and new object to json and comparing the resulting strings?

Comment: I'm just gonna [leave this here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects/) ;-)

Comment: Also, depending on situation, you might detect if something has changed already in UpdateDocument function. I suppose there you already do something like agreement.SomeProperty = document.SomeProperty. You might also track if any individual property has changed and return that from UpdateDocument.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Great idea, I will try this.

Comment: @RB. I try not to be dependant on third party libraries as much as I can but thank you anyway!

Comment: @Evk Thanks for the tip but I have decided to go with LasseV.Karlsen:s solution already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the tip from @LasseV.Karlsen. One problem I had was DateTimes however. When I compared the DateTime object in C# they were equal but when the metod `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` was called they generated a different time string. These were the strings generated `2016-10-21T10:42:09+02:00` and `2016-10-21T10:42:09`.

I solved this by extending `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter` like the code below. Afterwards all DateTime objects had the same format.

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz";
    }
}
```

Working method example:

```
//CloneJson is the extension method from above - Deep copy
var oldAgreement = agreement.CloneJson();

var document = client.GetThirdPartyAgreement(agreement.AgreementDocumentId);

UpdateDocument(agreement, document);

var agreementString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(agreement, new CustomDateTimeConverter());
var oldAgreementString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oldAgreement, new CustomDateTimeConverter());

if (agreementString != oldAgreementString)
{
    agreementRepository.Update(agreement);
}
```